# What does 'to sleep late' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does the phrase:

> I slept late yesterday.

or

> He sleeps late on Sundays.

mean?

Comment: to [sleep late](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sleep+late) - to sleep later than usual or customary; *to sleep in*.

Comment: @CopperKettle Googled it too. But would you say that in real-world conversation?

Comment: I guess I would, because I've just checked Google Books and there are instances of it being used. ("[For example, when a student makes an error such as, ”I sleep late” (meaning ”I slept late”), the teacher can write the error and the correction on the blackboard for the student to see.](https://books.google.ru/books?id=HBUgNRvBVFQC&pg=PA187&dq=%22I+slept+late%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=VMXQVMebDIr6ywOu5oGoCQ&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20slept%20late%22&f=false)")

Comment: .. and [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+slept+late%2Cshe+sleeps+late%2C+he+slept+late&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20slept%20late%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20sleeps%20late%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20slept%20late%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Absolutely colloquial, to sleep late, to sleep in. To sleep for a longer time than usual.  To *sleep late* can imply you had things to do, but missed. To *sleep in* implies that you have the freedom to do so, i.e. no early morning tasks/meetings etc.

Answer (score 3):

"To sleep late" means sleeping longer than usual, staying in bed longer than usual in the morning. It does **not** mean "go to bed later at night" or "stay up late".